# InvalidateRect ahead of time

Tags: c++, winapi

.h:

```
struct RRECT
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

Bitmap* bitmap;
RRECT position;
void Button::SetImage(HDC g)
{
    Graphics graphics(g);
    DrawImage(bitmap,0,0,width,height);
}
void Button::CreateImage(HDC hdc)
{
    invalidateButton(hwnd);
    SetImage(hdc);
}
void Button::invalidateButton(HWND hWnd)
{
    RECT rect = Helper::getAbsoluteRect(position);
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect, true);

}
```

WM_PAINT:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    childCloseButton = new Button(new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), new Bitmap(L"close.png"), new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), hdc);
        childCloseButton->position.x = p.x - 35;
        childCloseButton->position.y = 10;
        childCloseButton->position.height = bitmap->GetHeight();
        childCloseButton->position.width = bitmap->GetWidth();
    childCloseButton->CreateImage(gt);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

I am trying to update the region before drawing a new image, but it updates after I have drawn the image, how do I make the region update first, and then the picture is drawn
if I remove **InvalidateRect** from the **invalidateButton()** method, and add it to **WM_PAINT**:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
childCloseButton = new Button(new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), new Bitmap(L"close.png"), new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), hdc);
childCloseButton->position.x = p.x - 35;
childCloseButton->position.y = 10;
childCloseButton->position.height = bitmap->GetHeight();
childCloseButton->position.width = bitmap->GetWidth();
childCloseButton->CreateImage(gt);
childCloseButton->invalidateButton(hwnd);
childCloseButton->position.x = p.x - 35;
childCloseButton->position.y = 10;
childCloseButton->CreateImage(gt);
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

its working good

**EDIT**

```
LoadFils(){
childCloseButton = new Button(new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), new Bitmap(L"close.png"), new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), hdc);
    childCloseButton->position.x = p.x - 35;
    childCloseButton->position.y = 10;
    childCloseButton->position.height = bitmap->GetHeight();
    childCloseButton->position.width = bitmap->GetWidth();

}

WM_CREATE:
{
    LoadFils();
}

WM_PAINT:{

    childCloseButton->CreateImage(gt);
    childCloseButton->position.x = 55;
    childCloseButton->position.y = 25;
    childCloseButton->CreateImage(gt);

}
```

Comment: You could add UpdateWindow(hWnd); after the InvalidateRect call, but it is but a hack to do what you asked for.  Minimize the window and restore it to see the bigger problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I just need to update the region to draw a new image

Comment: Are you trying to draw onto the same `HWND` you are invalidating? If so, then you should draw the new image in the window's `WM_PAINT` handler. Your example is not detailed enough to know what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added a few details, I hope it will help

Comment: @RemyLebeau I draw in the same  HWND

Comment: You are doing things during `WM_PAINT` that don't belong there. Create and initialize your objects *outside* of `WM_PAINT`. You should *ONLY* be drawing in `WM_PAINT`, nothing else. Invalidate the window to trigger a repaint when the conditions of the drawing change.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I draw only in WM_PAINT, as I said, the problem is only if I call it in the method

Comment: You are doing much more than just drawing in `WM_PAINT`.  You are creating objects, loading files, positioning/sizing the button, re-invalidating the `HWND` that is actively being drawn, etc.  ALL of that logic needs to be moved OUTSIDE of `WM_PAINT`. `WM_PAINT` should be drawing the current button/image as-is.  Any and all changes to the button/image need to be OUTSIDE of `WM_PAINT`, using  `InvalidateRect()` to trigger `WM_PAINT` as soon as is convenient for the OS.

Comment: @RemyLebeau after I removed the loading, I left only changing the coordinates to check **invalidateButton()**, as a result, zeroing through the method does not work either, only if you declare it when drawing the second time. Check edit in question

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `WM_PAINT` is to only *DRAW A WINDOW'S CONTENT*, do nothing else in there.  All of your image preparation needs to be done outside of the `WM_PAINT` handler.  Have `WM_PAINT` simply draw the current image as-is. You can `InvalidateRect()` the window whenever the conditions of the drawing change.

Try something more like this:

```
struct RRECT
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

class Button
{
public:
    Bitmap* bitmap;
    RRECT position;
    HWND parentWnd;
    ...
    Button(Bitmap*, Bitmap*, Bitmap*);
    void Draw(HDC);
    void Invalidate();
};

Button::Button(Bitmap*, Bitmap*, Bitmap*)
{
    ...
}

void Button::Draw(HDC g)
{
    Graphics graphics(g);
    graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, Point(position.x, position.y));
}

void Button::Invalidate()
{
    InvalidateRect(parentWnd, &position, TRUE);
}
```

```
Button* childCloseButton;

void LoadFils(HWND hwnd)
{
    childCloseButton = new Button(new Bitmap(L"close2.png"), new Bitmap(L"close.png"), new Bitmap(L"close2.png"));
    childCloseButton->parentWnd = hwnd;
    childCloseButton->position.x = ...;
    childCloseButton->position.y = ...;
    childCloseButton->position.height = bitmap->GetHeight();
    childCloseButton->position.width = bitmap->GetWidth();
    childCloseButton->Invalidate();
}

...

case WM_CREATE: {
    LoadFils(hwnd);
    break;
}

case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    childCloseButton->Draw(hdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm trying to make sure that when drawing a new image from, the old one is erased, if I add it to LoadFiles, then everything will be erased

Comment: That is very easy to handle if you follow the approach I described. `WM_PAINT` should be drawing only the currently loaded image. After loading a new image, you would simply invalidate the window, and the next repaint will draw only the new image, not the old image.

Comment: ok, but how to achieve this with encapsulation?

Comment: The code I showed is already encapsulated. If you need to, add a `SetImage(Bitmap*)` to the `Button`, have it save the new `Bitmap`, and and then `Invalidate()`.  The next repaint will call `Draw()` to draw the new bitmap.

Comment: ok, but why my code didnt work? `void Button::CreateImage(HDC hdc)
{
    invalidateButton(hwnd);
    SetImage(hdc);
}`. why was my image erased? I used Invalidate() before rendering

Comment: Because you were drawing on the window too soon.  The window wasn't being painted by the OS yet. `InvalidateRect()` merely marks a window for repainting. The window is not actually repainted by the OS until the parent thread's message queue, or an explicit call to `UpdateWindow()` or `RedrawWindow()`, generates a new `WM_PAINT` to paint the window. At which time, anything that was on the window gets erased and redrawn. This is basic Win32 GDI stuff, I suggest you stop what you are doing and go read MSDN's doumentation more carefully.

Comment: that is, through the methods of the class, I will not be able to achieve a result?

Comment: @RobY I already answered that.